# How can collectstatic ignore a subdirectory?

Tags: django

This works:

```
./manage.py collectstatic -i bower_components
```

This does not:

```
./manage.py collectstatic -i bower_components/owl-carousel2
```

It seems that `/` isn't allowed in the pattern becasue this also doesn't work:

```
./manage.py collectstatic -i bower_components/
```

I would like to exclude `bower_components/owl-carousel2/src` because the static manifest collector fails and I don't need that directory. How can I skip this folder with the pattern?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can not do that with "collectstatic". You can use filter only by file name or directory, not path.

You can ignore src folder, but that could also ignore something important in a different place.

```
./manage.py collectstatic -i src
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a path to Django's ignore pattern list so that it is always ignored on collectstatic.

From the [documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)

The default ignored pattern list, ['CVS', '.*', '*~'], can be customized in a more persistent way than providing the --ignore command option at each collectstatic invocation. Provide a custom AppConfig class, override the ignore_patterns attribute of this class and replace 'django.contrib.staticfiles' with that class path in your INSTALLED_APPS setting:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.apps import StaticFilesConfig

class MyStaticFilesConfig(StaticFilesConfig):
    ignore_patterns = [...]  # your custom ignore list
```

Comment: Do you have an working example? Whenever I replacedjango.contrib.staticfiles' with that class path in my INST 'ALLED_APPS  it stops recognizing the collectstatic command

Comment: I don't, here's django's documentation on it that I got this answer from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Answer (score 1):

`collectstatic --ignore` will support paths in [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.2/#django-contrib-staticfiles).